# Google API Key failed on google urlshortener api

Tags: android, google-api, short-url

I have got this error message when using Google urlshortener api by ApiKey:
(I have using same API Key for showing Google Map in same app without any problem)
Where I did wrong?

> com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403
>   Forbidden
>                                                                           "code": 403,
>                                                                             "errors": [
>                                                                               {
>                                                                                 "domain": "usageLimits",
>                                                                                 "message": "The Android package name and signing-certificate
>   fingerprint, null and null, do not match the app restrictions
>   configured on your API key. Please use the API Console to update your
>   key restrictions.",
>                                                                                 "reason": "ipRefererBlocked",
>                                                                                 "extendedHelp":
>   "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=xxxx"
>                                                                               }
>                                                                             ],>                                                                           "message": "The Android package name and signing-certificate
>   fingerprint, null and null, do not match the app restrictions
>   configured on your API key. Please use the API Console to update your
>   key restrictions."*

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the Browser key, not the android key.